# Can't connect to Docker container of Spring Boot application using `docker exec`

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-image, buildpack, paketo

[Reproducer](https://github.com/rkudryashov/sb-repro)

After start the project, I can't connect to the container using `docker exec -it sb-repro [bash | sh]`. The error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Is any shell available? Or is it needed to explicitly add some buildpack [here](https://github.com/rkudryashov/sb-repro/blob/master/build.gradle.kts#L45)?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], not just an external link?  I wouldn't normally expect to get a shell inside a running JVM or Spring Boot application; what makes this an important use case for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build your container image, you used [this specific buildpack](https://github.com/rkudryashov/sb-repro/blob/master/build.gradle.kts#L45):

```
buildpacks.set(listOf("gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image"))
```

and you also [used the GraalVM Native build tool](https://github.com/rkudryashov/sb-repro/blob/master/build.gradle.kts#L8):

```
id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native")
```

If you look at the [Gradle Spring Boot plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization), you'll notice that using the build tool makes the plugin use `paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-tiny:latest` instead of `paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest` :

> paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest or paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-tiny:latest when GraalVM Native Image plugin is applied.

And to make the image size smaller, the `tiny` variant does not embed common Unix tools such as `bash` nor `sh` - which makes the built images even more secure (smaller attack surface) - but less debugable too...

I suggest you debug using the `paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest` base image, run your build with

```
./gradlew --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest bootBuildImage
```

or updating your `build.gradle.kts` with:

```
tasks.withType<BootBuildImage> {
    builder.set("paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest")
    ...
}
```